# Relationship between distribution & package manager

Tags: linux, package-management, distributions

A little consideration will show that each/every Linux distribution correlates/associates with a specific Package Manager.

For example:

- **APT**: Debain Family (Debian, Ubuntu, Mint, etc.)
- **RPM**: RedHat Family (RedHat, Fedora, etc.)

Is each Linux distribution based on (only) a particular/specific package manager?

Or can another/any Package manager be used on different Linux distributions (for example: using Nix on Debian)?

**What is the relation/interaction between a Linux distribution & it's Package Manager?**

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: package managers are highly integrated into their distribution. You *may* use a foreign package manager on your distribution, but this can lead to unstable, not up-to-date, redundant installation.

---

#### Long answer

A package manager keeps track of your system components and configuration:

- Librairies
- Softwares
- Configuration files
- Versions
- Architecture

This imply that a package manager *knows* where everything is installed and how, and respect the distribution *rules* when installing new packages.
Also, some package manager like `Portage` (on Gentoo) *install* packages by building them from sources. `APT` or `RPM` install pre-compiled packages.

If you use two different package managers side by side, they may override each other: install duplicate files at different places, override configuration files, replace dependencies (ex: libraries) by new versions incompatible with the rest of the system, ...

Now, in theory, you *can* use several packages managers on a single system. But you'll need to configure and adapt them carefully.

---

#### Other options

Tools like [PackageKit](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/PackageKit/) provides the same interface to install and manage packages on several distribution. It doesn't replace the system's default package manager, but wrap it.

[Alien](https://wiki.debian.org/Alien) can be used to convert `rpm` packages to `deb` packages.

Answer (score 1):

You will generally find each distribution prefers one package manager system. Package managers have been ported to other distributions (e.g. APT is available for RH-type distros), but using a foreign package manager may not work well with the distro.

Answer (score 1):

[Pacman](https://www.archlinux.org/pacman/) is a distro-agnostic package manager: it was originally developed for [Arch Linux](https://archlinux.org/), but is now used by a variety of distributions, including all of the Arch derivatives *and* some that are *not* Arch-based, such as:

- [Chakra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chakra_(operating_system)) (originally an Arch derivative, now idependent)
- [DeLi Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DeLi_Linux)
- [Frugalware Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frugalware_Linux)